# Django : object_set vs filter

Tags: django, django-models

Consider the following:

I have an images model which uses a brand as a foreign key.

```
brand = Brand.objects.get(id = whatever)
```

I could retrieve all the images associated with that model with either of these ways:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(brand = brand)
```

or

```
images = brand.image_set.all()
```

From a performance standpoint, which one of these is faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There won't be any performance differences. In both cases the generated SQL query will be the same.

Therefore which one you choose is a matter of taste. Personally, I prefer

```
images = Image.objects.filter(brand=brand)
```

because it is very clear that you are returning a queryset of images.

However, you could argue that

```
images = brand.image_set.all()
```

is safer, because the brand filtering is automatic, whereas in the other way you could forget to filter on `brand=brand`.

Comment: I guess it also depends the context you are using it, but with image_set you there is less code because you are not directly importing the model?

Comment: @alias51 I don't think the import would have any measurable impact on performace - the `Image` model has to be loaded either way.

Comment: Could you point to a reference that states the point that the generated SQL query is the same in both cases? I would like to read up more on this.

Comment: @Chintan No, I can’t find a definitive reference that states that the queries are the same. You’ll just have to trust me, or you could try running the queries yourself and checking `connection.queries`. You might find [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) docs useful.